# Last Logon Time of All Users - RDP server not on a domain

Tags: windows-server-2012, login

I am attempting to get a list of "last logon time" of "all users" on Windows Server 2012, but currently only know of how to list a single user login, which is:

`net user username | findstr /B /C:"Last logon"`

Any ideas?

*P.S. This servers only purpose is to host the RDP connections; not tied to a domain/AD.

Comment: Unless your rdp users are in a separate silo then it is active directory, please state how users authenticate to sessions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **local** users, you can use Powershell with ADSI as follows.

```
$comp=[adsi]"WinNT://$($env:ComputerName)"
$users = $comp.Children | ?{ $_.SchemaClassName -eq 'User' }
$users | select @{L="Name";E={$_.psbase.Properties.Name.Value}},@{L="LastLogin";E={$_.psbase.Properties.LastLogin.Value}}
```

Comment: *I forgot to mention: This servers only purpose is to host the RDP connections; not tied to a domain/AD.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered similar problem a while ago. This was the code that produced the results I needed. Works even for local accounts.

`$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$adsi.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} | ft name,lastlogin`

Kudos to Anthony Howell in [this discussion](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/343893-list-all-local-users-last-logon-time).

Comment: The questions appear to be merged into one now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a domain, create a powershell script like that;

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

function Get-ADUsersLastLogon()
{
  $dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter {Name -like "*"}
  $users = Get-ADUser -Filter *
  $time = 0
  $exportFilePath = "c:\lastLogon.csv"
  $columns = "name,username,datetime"

  Out-File -filepath $exportFilePath -force -InputObject $columns

  foreach($user in $users)
  {
    foreach($dc in $dcs)
    { 
      $hostname = $dc.HostName
      $currentUser = Get-ADUser $user.SamAccountName | Get-ADObject -Server $hostname -Properties lastLogon

      if($currentUser.LastLogon -gt $time) 
      {
        $time = $currentUser.LastLogon
      }
    }

    $dt = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($time)
    $row = $user.Name+","+$user.SamAccountName+","+$dt

    Out-File -filepath $exportFilePath -append -noclobber -InputObject $row

    $time = 0
  }
}

Get-ADUsersLastLogon
```

Took from [there](https://www.interworks.com/blog/trhymer/2014/01/22/powershell-get-last-logon-all-users-across-all-domain-controllers)

Comment: *I forgot to mention: This servers only purpose is to host the RDP connections; not tied to a domain/AD.

Answer (score 1):

Good day. Some years later, I answer this question :)

Maybe someone, like me, find this useful.

Use WMI to query the objet Win32_UserProfile (in each server, no matter if in a domain or not) and obtain the fields 'LocalPath' and 'LastUseTime' (at least). Match the last section of the Path with your AD (If needed) to provide more information.

We needed it some months ago, and it worked like a charm. We remotely pushed it to all the servers through PS-Invoke and export the results to a .csv for batch processing.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ee886409(v%3Dvs.85)